# Mule calling rest api fails with " Response code 404 mapped as failure. "

Tags: http, mule, anypoint-studio, connector

I am trying to consume a rest api via mulesoft but from postman when i invoke the mule endpoint it gives the following error "Response code 404 mapped as failure."

```
 <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="xxxxx" port="80"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="/xxx/Members"/>
 <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/{mID}/Members" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:uri-param paramName="mID" value="#[flowVars.memID]"/>
        </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting in Mule indicates that the REST API you are calling from Mule is returning a 404. This means that you are requesting a resource that doesn't exist.

Check your config and the service you are consuming to make sure they match. From your code above the URL that Mule will be requesting is:

`http://xxxxx:80/xxx/Members/{mID}/Members`

This is built up from the host, port and base path of the HTTP config along with the path of the HTTP Request component.

Not having any knowledge of the API you are trying to consume I can't tell you what it should be in your specific case. If you have documentation that describes the service you should be able to adjust your mule configuration to match it.

Hope that helps.

Johnson.